# Using HTML in CSS After Tag for Hover State

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

I am currently trying to pass in some html into the the :after pseudo class in css to add an arrow after a link once hovered on.  I have seen this done quite some time ago in the stock WordPress theme that used to ship with the default install.  I feel like I must me missing something simple.

```
a:hover:after{content: "&raquo;"}
```

thank in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the hex value `\00BB`.

http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/AGDbH/

Comment: Thanks Dustin!  I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Nifty little tool to convert for you: http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for, I think:

```
a:hover:after
{
content: "\00bb";
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8vghp/)

Link to reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use the hex value instead of `&raquo;`?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why CSS relies upon this method of character encoding, but the 'particular reason' is that it works this way. Which is a bad, bad, unhelpful answer...