# CSS Adding a triangle

Tags: css

I have an  tag, with the following markup:

```
#leftMenu ul li a   {color: #111; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
```

And I want to be able to hover over it, and display a triangular end.  Similar to this shape:

http://www.promotionalpromo.com/Upfiles/Prod_v/1-7-8-x-2-7-8--Long-Arrow_2010017055476.jpg

But not with the same dimensions, more along the lines of:
`width: 200px; height: 20px;`

Either I chop the two ends, (border-top-right and border-bottom-right) or I add css on with :after, however I need all this to happen when the user hovers of the  tag.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this site very usefull :
http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

when i needed to create triangles.
it generates a triangle for you.

Now after u generate the triangle, all u need to do is use `:before` or `:after` on your desired element to make it work, in your case hover as well.

Comment: But you cannot write 'a:hover:after' can you?

Comment: you can, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226764/using-html-in-css-after-tag-for-hover-state

Comment: this tutorial should help u get the hang of it : http://speckyboy.com/2012/02/15/how-to-build-a-stylish-css3-search-box/

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference this is how I did it:

```
#leftMenu ul li a   {color: #111; text-decoration: none; display: block; position: relative;}
#leftMenu ul li a:hover {color: #555; text-decoration: underline; background: #EEE; }
#leftMenu ul li a:hover:after 
            {
                content:"";
                float:right;
                position:absolute; top:0; right:-12px; width:0; height:0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 13px 0 12px 12px;
                border-color: transparent transparent transparent #EEE;
            }
```